# ES6 class - TS type for `this` with also the private properties (e.g. when passing `this` to callback)

Tags: typescript

I would like to set a proper TS type for the internal `this`, when passing its reference e.g. to a callback.

Imagine the following situation:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor (props) {
    this.props = props;
  }

  private method1 () {

  }    

  private method2 () {
    this.props.someCallback(this);
  }

  public method3 () {
  
  }
}

const foo = new Foo({
  someCallback: (context: Foo) => {
    // `context` contains all the internal properties and methods, but TS will
    // throw error for the next line, because the `Context` type refers only
    // the publicly available properties and methods.
    // @ts-ignore
    context.method1();
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Private decorated properties cannot be accessed or invoked outside the class itself. If that is confusing - private properties can be accessed between the curly brackets of the class.

```js
class Foo {
// you can access private properties only here
}
```

[Typescript understanding-typescripts-private](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#understanding-typescripts-private)

If it is intended to be hidden - keep it private and do not use it outside the class.

If it is intended as a public API -you should modify it as public.